# CSS: prevent column from growing in display: table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table with 2 columns and 2 rows. I'd like the first column to take only as much space as is needed, but it's taking up 50% of the space:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table-row'>
    <div class='table-cell a'>a1</div>
    <div class='table-cell b'>b1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='table-row'>
    <div class='table-cell a'>a2</div>
    <div class='table-cell b'>b2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content in the first column has variable width, so I can't set a static width on that column.

Using a table display, how can I make the first column take up only as much space as is needed? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give a width of 0px to all of your cells in the first-column. When the content is larger than the specified width, then the width argument is ignored. The cell with the largest content will determine the total width of the first column.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table-cell.a {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table-row'>
    <div class='table-cell a'>a1</div>
    <div class='table-cell b'>b1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='table-row'>
    <div class='table-cell a'>a2</div>
    <div class='table-cell b'>b2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love a good hack in the morning

Comment: @duhaime it won't work in all the cases: https://jsfiddle.net/Lagfcpu8/

Comment: blast. Is there a more general solution? `white-space: nowrap` on `.a` helps here but sometimes you just gotta rap: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yXJ4t6Ax1U

Comment: @duhaime simply remove width:100%, I don't see why you need it